# Where is the unexpected token here in this Meteor/MongoDB line of code?

Tags: mongodb, meteor, mongodb-query, meteor-helper

I'm trying to filter the results of a MongoDB find() in my Meteor app in this way:

```
Template.tblScheduler.helpers({
  jobLocations: function() {

    // return JobLocations.find();
    return JobLocations.find({jl_jobloc}, {sort: {jl_jobloc: 1}});
  }
});
```

The commented out "cartesian result set" code works just fine, but I only need the one field in this case, and want them to be fetched in alphabetical order.

The app won't compile, though, complaining about line 40 of this line:

```
return JobLocations.find({jl_jobloc}, {sort: {jl_jobloc: 1}});
```

(which is the first "}" on that line).

What is wrong? Why is the "}" considered an "Unexpected token"?

Comment: Everthing within the braces there `{}` needs to be a "key/value" pair combination like `{ "a": 1 }` or just like your `{ sort: { jl_jobloc: 1 } }`. So there is another way to select the field only itself, but `{ jl_jobloc }` is never going to be valid JavaScript notation for an object since it is not a "pair".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The selector is incorrect in the find function

According to the docs, http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/find

The first argument is the selector

> {} - selects all documents

The second argument is an object consisting:

> sort: {jl_jobloc: 1}   - sorts the documents by jl_jobloc
>
> fields: {jl_jobloc: 1} - returns only the jl_jobloc field

To put it all together to get what you need, try this:

```
return JobLocations.find({}, {sort: {jl_jobloc: 1}, fields: {jl_jobloc: 1}});
```